# Submit Javascript variables to another PHP file using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function () { //The page has been loaded...
    var ref = document.referrer; //Referrer
    var curpg = document.location.href; //Current page URL
    var dataSet = 'ref=' + ref + '&curpg=' curpg + '&shizz1e=21';

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.domainname.com/ajaxreceiver.php",
        data: dataSet
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

I am trying to submit the 'curpg', 'ref', and 'shizz1e' variables to ajaxreceiver.php as soon as the page loads, without any user intervention. I am also trying to avoid having the page refresh or redirect the client to ajaxreceiver.php. I'm not sure why this code isn't working; the dataSet variable never gets sent to ajaxreceiver.php.

Comment: What makes you sure, the variable never gest sent? Do you see any requests in the network tab of your webdev tools? How does the php script look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have to see your server-side PHP code because your JavaScript code looks OK to me. I think it should work.

Try this rewriting it like this, though:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        var referrer = document.referrer;
        var current_page_url = $(location).attr('href');
        var data_object = {
            'ref':        referrer,
            'curpg':      current_page_url,
            'shizz1e':    '21'
        };

        $.ajax({
            'url':        "http://your.url.com/php_script.php",
            'data':       data_object,
            'success':    function (return_data) {
                // Do something on success.
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is just a bit cleaner in my opinion. Please show some of your server-side PHP code, so I can really help you find out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be sending a URL as a parameter you're going to have to escape certain characters within it, using the [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) or [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) functions.

Answer (score 0):

1) make sure, your request gets actually sent - check your networktab and add those handlers to have some debug-help:

```
$.ajax({/*...*/})
   .done(function()  { console.log("success"); })
   .fail(function(jqXHR, status)  { console.log("error: "+status); })
   .always(function(){ console.log("complete"); });
```

2) Did you accidently do a forbidden [cross-domain call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)? `http://www.domainname.com` and `http://domainname.com` is a common example causing this issue. Use a realtive path instead: `/ajaxreceiver.php` is enough.

3) provide your php code, so that we can check for errors in there. Perhaps you accidently used `[POST]` or some tiny mistake like that.

Comment: 1) edit: nevermind, figured this part out, will report back in a second.


2) Nope, checked those, and even tried changing everything to relative paths. Still not working.


3) Working on cleaning it up so I can post it.

Comment: @user1610772 did you make progress with your problem`